# How do I find mutiple variables in a string?

Tags: php

I have a script which checks the variable `$hello` to see if it contains "pink", "blue" and "red". For each variable it contains, some text is added to the string `$finalstring`.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
$hello = "pink*blue*red*orange";
$finalstring = "";

if (strpos($hello, "pink") == true) {
    $finalstring .= "_pink";
}

if (strpos($hello, "blue") == true) {
    $finalstring .= "_blue";
}

if (strpos($hello, "red") == true) {
    $finalstring .= "_red";
}

echo $finalstring; // output: _pink_blue_red
```

Comment: you cannot replace the `*` with `_`?

Comment: It's just an example, but no, replacing `*` wouldnt get rid of `"orange"`. `"orange"` represents an unknown string of text, so I cant just replace `*` and then replace `orange`.

Comment: Why don't you use an array to store those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$finalstring = '';

$items = array('pink', 'blue', 'red');
foreach($items as $item)
{
   if(strpos($hello, $item) !== false)
   {
       $finalstring .= '_' . $item;
   }
}
```

Comment: I know this is less code, but is it more efficient? It seems like it does exactly the same thing as my code in the sense that it has to go through the same string 3 times to check for the variables. Is there a way to check for all three in one strpos?

Comment: @supercoolville:  If you plan on adding more cases, this will be better as you only have to add a new item to the array, not an entire new `if` condition.  Efficiency, in this case, is something that you should not be concerning yourself over.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with all values you want to check for (`$types`), iterate through all values and check if they can be found in your string…

```
$hello = "pink*blue*red*orange";
$finalstring = "";
$types = array('pink', 'blue', 'red');
foreach ($types as $type) {
  if (stristr($hello, $type)) {
    $finalstring .= '_' . $type;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function yourFunction($input, $keywords){
    $result = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($keywords); $i++){
        if(strpos($input, $keywords[$i]) !== FALSE)
            $result .= "_" . $keywords[$i];
    }

    return $result;
}

$finalString = yourFunction("pink*blue*red*orange", Array("pink", "blue", "red"));

echo $finalString;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hello = "pink*blue*red*orange";
$finalstring = "";
getString($finalstring, "pink");
getString($finalstring, "blue");
getString($finalstring, "red");
echo $finalstring;

    function getString($mainString, $word){
        if (strpos($mainString, $word) == true) {
           $finalstring .= "_".$word;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

using **regular expressions**:

```
$hello = "pink*blue*red*orange";
$colors = array('pink', 'blue', 'orange'); 
if(!preg_match_all(sprintf("/%s/", join('|', $colors)), $hello, $match))
{
    die('not found any color');
}
$finalstring = '_'. join('_', $match[0]);
echo $finalstring; // _pink_blue_orange
```